# Reponsive styling Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scroll, css-position

I am developing a wordpress them and the homepage consists of a fixed header and footer and a vertical slider in the middle including content and images. I am building the website responsive but what I am noticing is that when the screen is resized the content in the vertical sliders is being cut off(Forget the images - just the boxes with the title and text). How can I make the main cont always start beneath the header and above the footer ?

Here is a js fiddle of what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/tdWb9/

Some css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}


    /* Style for our header texts 
    * --------------------------------------- */
    h1{
        font-size: 4em; 
        color: #fff;
        margin:0;
        padding :0;
    }

html,body{
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.home-button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #cae3fc;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #cae3fc;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #cae3fc;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #79bbff), color-stop(1, #00baf2) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #79bbff 5%, #00baf2 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#79bbff', endColorstr='#00baf2');
    background-color:#79bbff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #469df5;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:38px;
    line-height:38px;
    width:128px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #287ace;
}
.home-button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #00baf2), color-stop(1, #79bbff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #00baf2 5%, #79bbff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00baf2', endColorstr='#79bbff');
    background-color:#00baf2;
}.home-button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.home-button h3{
text-align:center;
}

.intro{
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
width:30%;
border-radius:10px;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-left:3%;
padding-right:3%;
margin-left:10%;
}   

.intro2{
            background-color:white;
            width:30%;
            border-radius:10px;
opacity:0.8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80);
padding-bottom:20px;
margin-right:10%;
float:right;
}

    .intro h1, .intro2 h1{
    color:black;
    padding-top:3%;
        }

    .intro p, .intro2 p{
        color: black;
    }

    /* Centered texts in each section 
    * --------------------------------------- */
    .section{
        text-align:left;
    }

    /* Backgrounds will cover all the section
    * --------------------------------------- */
    #section0,
    #section1,
    #section2,
    #section3{
        background-size: cover;
    }

    /* Defining each sectino background and styles 
    * --------------------------------------- */
    #section0{
        background-image: url(images/image1.jpg);
    }


    #section2{
        background-image: url(images/image2.jpg);
    }
    #section3{
        background-image: url(images/image3.jpg);
    }

    /* Overwriting styles for control arrows for slides
    * --------------------------------------- */
    .controlArrow.prev {
        left: 50px;
    }
    .controlArrow.next{
        right: 50px;
    }

    /* Fixed header and footer.
    * --------------------------------------- */
    #header, #footer{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #05556d;
    text-align:center;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
#footer{
    padding:10px 0px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.home #header, .home #footer{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9;
}
.home #header{
    top:0px;
}
.home #footer{
    bottom:0px;
}

#footer a{
        color:#00baf2;
    }

    #footer-other{
        z-index:9999;
        width: 100%;
        background: #05556d;
        text-align:center;
        color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    #footer-other{
        padding:10px 0px;
        font-size:12px;
    }

#footer-other a{
        color:#00baf2;
    }

    /* Bottom menu
    * --------------------------------------- */
    #infoMenu {
        bottom: 80px;
    }
    #infoMenu li a {
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    *Main Menu CSS*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);
#cssmenu {padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;}
#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {position: relative; z-index: 597; }
#cssmenu ul li { float: left; min-height: 1px; vertical-align: middle;}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default;}
#cssmenu ul ul {visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598;}
#cssmenu ul ul li {float: none;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {top: 0; left: auto; right: -99.5%; }
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul {bottom: 0; left: 0;}
#cssmenu ul ul {margin-top: 0; }
#cssmenu ul ul li {font-weight: normal;}
#cssmenu a { display: block; line-height: 1em; text-decoration: none; }

#cssmenu {
  background: #05556d;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #00baf2;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

  #cssmenu > ul { *display: inline-block; }

  #cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
}

#cssmenu a {
    background: #05556d;
    color: #CBCBCB;
    padding: 0 20px; 
}
#cssmenu ul { text-transform: uppercase; }

    #cssmenu ul ul {
      border-top: 4px solid #1b9bff;
      text-transform: none;
      min-width: 190px; 
}
      #cssmenu ul ul a {
        background: #1b9bff;
        color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #0082e7;
        border-top: 0 none;
        line-height: 150%;
        padding: 16px 20px; 
}
      #cssmenu ul ul ul { border-top: 0 none; }

      #cssmenu ul ul li { position: relative }

#cssmenu > ul > li > a { line-height: 80px;  }

#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a { border-top: 1px solid #0082e7; }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a { background: #00baf2; }

        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
          border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff; 
}
        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child:hover > a { border-radius: 0 0 0 3px; }

        #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
          content: '+';
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          right: 15px;
          margin-top: -8px;
}

 #cssmenu ul li:hover > a, #cssmenu ul li.current-menu-item > a {
      background: #00baf2;
      color: #FFF;
}
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
      content: '+';
      margin-left: 5px; 
}

#down{display:none}

    #cssmenu ul li.last ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 0; 
}
      #cssmenu ul li.last ul ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 99.5%;
}

.logo{
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20%;
    padding-right:10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10000;

}

@Media screen and (max-width:480px) { 

.intro{
width:70%;
margin-top:20%;
}

.intro h1, .intro2 h1{
    color:black;
    padding-top:3%;
        }

    .intro p, .intro2 p{
        color: black;
    }

.main-container{
width:85% !important;
}

    #sbs{position: absolute;
width: 20px;
padding: 8px;
cursor:pointer;
height: 20px;
border: 0px solid white;
border-radius: 5px;
top: 5px;
left: 10px;}


    .sb{width: 100%;
height: 4px;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
float: left;
clear: both;}
    #down{cursor:pointer;display:table;width:350px; margin:0 auto; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center;padding: 15px 0px; background: #00baf2; color: white;margin-top: 10px;position:relative;}

    #cssmenu *:not{ float :left !important; width: 100%;padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important;}
#cssmenu {
width: 87%;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
}
        #down + #cssmenu { display: none;}
        #down.open + #cssmenu { display: block;}
    .logo{margin:0;padding:0;width: 100%;text-align: center;margin-bottom:10px;}
    #cssmenu .logo > a{margin:0;padding:0}
#cssmenu ul li {    display: block ;    width: 100% ;  text-align:center; } 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a { line-height: 50px;  }
#cssmenu ul ul {
border-top: 4px solid #1b9bff;
text-transform: none;
width: 100%;
/* float: left; */
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {display:none;}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
border-top: 0 none;
visibility:visible;
display: block;
float: left;
clear: both;
position:relative;
right: 0;
}
        #cssmenu ul li.hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover{
            display:inline-block;
        }
.content1{font-size:100%;}

}
}

@Media screen and (max-width:768px) {  
.logo{ margin-left:10%;}
}

.login{
    background-color:#00baf2;
    width:5%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-top:-60px;;
    float:right;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }

.main-container{
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:3%;
}

.imgsection{
    float:left;
    padding-right:5%;
    }

.main-container img{
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: It looks like there are a lot of defined max-width tags. Can you define a min-width?

Comment: @Klompengard - The max width in the media queries you mean ?

Comment: What @Klompengard said. Try starting this the other way around - small screen styles by default then add new styles at increasing `min-widths`. Think your problem here is mostly the menu formatting at mediumish sizes.

Comment: Can you amend my fiddle with your best practice solution from your end?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because the text wont feet all in the page because it's a slider, so when you pull down to see more text it will change to the next slider,
The best way that I find better and simpliest to do it is by adding this css code:

```
p {font-size:82%}
```

Or if you want to keep the font-size to 100% you can do it by adding this css code which makes the div scroll:

```
.section{
height:55%;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.intro{
height:55%;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I think the scroll will work fine as you drag the mobile mouse into the text area without conflict with changing to the next slide, but I can't tell for sure because I'm not testing it on a mobile, but you can do the test.

Or... in a last resort, you could create a smaller logo and put it on the left side of the menu and compact the header size.

Regards